# SSAS Tabular Dynamic Row Filter

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

Does anyone know how to create a dynamic row filter with multiple conditions?

I have a RoleSecurity table with user login, Region and BusinessUnit. I would like to create a dynamic row filter that incorporates both Region and BusinessUnit.

I already know how to create the filter using one condition. Below is an example.

```
=
'HR BASE'[Region]
    = LOOKUPVALUE (
        RoleSecurity[Region];
        RoleSecurity[UserLogin]; USERNAME ();
        RoleSecurity[Region]; 'HR BASE'[Region]
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

```
'HR BASE'[Region] =
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        RoleSecurity[Region];
        RoleSecurity[UserLogin]; USERNAME ();
        RoleSecurity[Region]; 'HR BASE'[Region]
    )
    && 'HR BASE'[BusinessUnit]
        = LOOKUPVALUE (
            RoleSecurity[BusinessUnitName];
            RoleSecurity[UserLogin]; USERNAME ();
            RoleSecurity[BusinessUnitName]; 'HR BASE'[BusinessUnit]
        )
```